# Visibility (scope) of variables in block handler

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scope, block

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS dev.

Are the `arg1` and `arg2` visible in `completionHandler` block, in following code ? If not what is the correct way to pass those variables to the block ?

```
- (void)addCurrentLocationNameToDB:(CLLocation *)location param1:(NSString*)arg1 param2:(NSString*)arg2 
{
     CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
     [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) 
     {
             [self locationNameDidReceive:locationName forLocation:location forTrip:arg1 waypoint:arg2];
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes just use them. Read more about blocks here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

(that is one big advantage of blocks - your nearly stay in your surrounding scope)